# Change SPWeb to a Particular Path Straight Away

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I would like to change my PowerShell script to define a `$spWeb` value to a particular site straight away in a site collection, instead of going through the multiple `foreach` loops.

Is it possible?

Code sample:

```
$url = "http://testweb.com"
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite $url 
$WebApp = $siteCollection.WebApplication 
$url = $url+"/sites/site1"
foreach ($Site in $WebApp.Sites) 
{
  foreach($spWeb in $Site.AllWebs) 
  { 
        if ($spWeb.URL -eq $url)
        {

//Skip previous foreach loops and declare $spWeb value with a fixed URL here

            $users = $spWeb.SiteUserInfoList
            $groups = $users.Items
            $RList = $spWeb.Lists["Records"]
            $RCount = 0

            #GET Records
            #$outputnewwebtext = "GET Records in $($spWeb.URL)"
            #$outputnewwebtext |Tee-Object MRCE_Records.txt -Append
            $query =  New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
            $query.Query = '<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Computed">Item</Value></Eq></Where>'
            $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
            $records = $Rlist.GetItems($query)
            for ($intIndex =$records.Count - 1; $intIndex -gt -1; $intIndex--)
            {
                $RCount ++
            }
            $outputnewwebtext = "Records in $($spWeb.URL): $RCount`n"
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Get-SPWeb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps) command.

```
Get-SPWeb http://sp10/sites/team1
```